# Combine result from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

This is my situation:

I have two tables **detailBefore** and **detailAfter**, I want to combine the results. This is my sample data:

Table **detailBefore**

```
| id  | kod_akun | detail   | volume | price |
| --- | -------- | -------- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 5.1      | produk1  | 10     | 100   |
| 2   | 5.1      | produk2  | 15     | 150   |
| 3   | 5.1      | produk3  | 5      | 200   |
| 4   | 5.1      | produk4  | 20     | 150   |
```

Table **detailAfter**

```
| id  | kod_akun | detail   | volume | price |
| --- | -------- | -------- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 5.1      | produk1  | 5      | 100   |
| 2   | 5.1      | produk2  | 10     | 100   |
| 3   | 5.1      | produk3  | 5      | 200   |
| 4   | 5.1      | produk4  | 10     | 200   |
| 5   | 5.1      | produk5  | 10     | 100   |
```

I want the result like this:

```
| kod_akun | detail   | volume_before | price_before | volume_after | price_after |
| -------- | -------- | ------------- | ------------ | ------------ | ----------- |
| 5.1      | produk1  | 10            | 100          | 5            | 100         |
| 5.1      | produk2  | 15            | 150          | 10           | 100         |
| 5.1      | produk3  | 5             | 200          | 5            | 200         |
| 5.1      | produk4  | 20            | 150          | 10           | 200         |
| 5.1      | produk5  | 0             | 0            | 10           | 100         |
```

I use PHP & MySQL.
How to get the results I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
total AS ( SELECT kod_akun, 
                  detail 
           FROM detailBefore
         UNION ALL
           SELECT kod_akun, 
                  detail 
           FROM detailAfter )
SELECT kod_akun, 
       detail,
       COALESCE(detailBefore.volume_before, 0) volume_before,
       COALESCE(detailBefore.price_before, 0) price_before,
       COALESCE(detailAfter.volume_after, 0) volume_after,
       COALESCE(detailAfter.price_after, 0) price_after
FROM total
LEFT JOIN detailBefore USING (kod_akun, detail)
LEFT JOIN detailAfter USING (kod_akun, detail)
```